# Does passing a json file as argument makes the rendering html template lose performances?

Tags: html, json, django

I have an html webpage: `quiz.html` returned by the urls.py script of a django application. The questions are just words that are rendered as a `ul` list of `input` boxes which I want to transform into related photos where I would be able to do a multi selection click on them. As the ul-input combination looks very heavy I wanted to transform it into a json file that I would pass as an argument of the related function in `urls.py` wouldn't make me lose performance and if it was a good practice?

```html
  
      <!-- Header -->
      <header class="intro-header">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="col-lg-5 mr-auto order-lg-2">
          <h3><br>Tell me something about you... </h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>
    
      <!-- Page Content -->
      <section class="content-section-a">
    
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-5 mr-auto order-lg-2">
              <div class="recommendations">
                <form action = "/getmatch" method="POST">
                  <p>
                    <label>Your gender</label>
                    <label><input type="radio" name="gender" value="女香">Female</label>
                    <label><input type="radio" name="gender" value="男香">Male</label>
                  </p>
              </div>
    
              <div>
                <p>
                  <dl class="dropdown">
                      <dt>
                        <span>Pick the keywords you want to express when wearing perfume</span>
                        <!-- <p class="multiSel"></p> -->
                      </dt>
                      <dd>
                          <div class="mutliSelect">
                              <ul>
                                  <li>
                                      <input type="checkbox" name='note' value="甜美" />Sweet</li>
                                  <li>
                                      <input type="checkbox" name='note' value="温柔" />Gentle</li>
                                  <li>
                                      <input type="checkbox" name='note' value="优雅" />Elegant</li>
                                  <li>
                                      <input type="checkbox" name='note' value="成熟" />Mature</li>
                                  <li>
                                      <input type="checkbox" name='note' value="性感" />Sexy</li>
                                  <li>
                                      <input type="checkbox" name='note' value="女人味" />Feminine</li>
                                  <li>
                                      <input type="checkbox" name='note' value="清新" />Fresh</li>
                                  <li>
                                      <input type="checkbox" name='note' value="经典" />Classy</li>
                                  <li>
                                      <input type="checkbox" name='note' value="淡雅" />Soft</li>
                                  <li>
                                      <input type="checkbox" name='note' value="平易近人" />Easygoing</li>
                                  <li>
                                      <input type="checkbox" name='note' value="邻家女孩" />The girl next door</li>
                                  <li>
                                      <input type="checkbox" name='note' value="少女" />Young lady</li>
                                  <li>
                                      <input type="checkbox" name='note' value="可爱" />Lovely</li>
                                  <li>
                                      <input type="checkbox" name='note' value="活泼" />Lively</li>
                                  <li>
                                      <input type="checkbox" name='note' value="干净" />Clean</li>
                                  <li>
                                      <input type="checkbox" name='note' value="夏天" />Summer</li>
                                  <li>
                                      <input type="checkbox" name='note' value="清爽" />Refreshing</li>
                                  <li>
                                      <input type="checkbox" name='note' value="温暖" />Warm</li>
                                  <li>
                                      <input type="checkbox" name='note' value="男人味" />Masculine</li>
                                  <li>
                                      <input type="checkbox" name='note' value="稳重" />Reliable</li>
                                  <li>
                                      <input type="checkbox" name='note' value="神秘" />Mysterious</li>
                                  <li>
                                      <input type="checkbox" name='note' value="深沉" />Low profile</li>
                                  <li>
                                      <input type="checkbox" name='note' value="浓郁" />Strong smell</li>
                                  <li>
                                      <input type="checkbox" name='note' value="冬天" />Winter</li>
                                  <li>
                                      <input type="checkbox" name='note' value="青草" />Grass</li>
                                  <li>
                                      <input type="checkbox" name='note' value="植物" />Plants</li>
                                  <li>
                                      <input type="checkbox" name='note' value="大牌" />Big brands</li>
                                  <li>
                                      <input type="checkbox" name='note' value="奢华" />Luxury</li>
                                  <li>
                                      <input type="checkbox" name='note' value="广为人知" />Well-known products</li>
                                  <li>
                                      <input type="checkbox" name='note' value="广告多见" />Usually see in ads</li>
                              </ul>
                          </div>
                      </dd>
                      <!-- <button>Filter</button> -->
                  </dl>
                </p>
              </div>
                    <p> <input type ="submit" value="Check Our Suggestions" /> </p>
                </form>
              </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.container -->
        </div>
      </section>
    
      <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
      <script src="static/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="static/vendor/popper/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="static/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I would do something like:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from todo import views

keywords = json.load('data/keywords.json')

urlpatterns = [
    ...

    # quizz
    path('quiz', views.quiz, name="quiz", {'keywords': keywords}),

]
```

And then the template would be much more simple with:

```
      <!-- Header -->
      <header class="intro-header">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="col-lg-5 mr-auto order-lg-2">
          <h3><br>Tell me something about you... </h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>
    
      <!-- Page Content -->
      <section class="content-section-a">
    
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-5 mr-auto order-lg-2">
              <div class="recommendations">
                <form action = "/getmatch" method="POST">
                  <p>
                    <label>Your gender</label>
                    <label><input type="radio" name="gender" value="女香">Female</label>
                    <label><input type="radio" name="gender" value="男香">Male</label>
                  </p>
              </div>
    
              <div>
                <p>
                  <dl class="dropdown">
                      <dt>
                        <span>Pick the keywords you want to express when wearing perfume</span>
                        <!-- <p class="multiSel"></p> -->
                      </dt>
                      <dd>
                            {% for keyword in keywords %}
                  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">

                    <h3>{{ keyword.name }}</h3>
                    <p>{{ keyword.image }}</p>
                
                  </div>
                  {% endfor %}
                      </dd>
                      <!-- <button>Filter</button> -->
                  </dl>
                </p>
              </div>
                    <p> <input type ="submit" value="Check Our Suggestions" /> </p>
                </form>
              </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.container -->
        </div>
      </section>
    
      <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
      <script src="static/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="static/vendor/popper/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="static/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into using Django's generic `FormView`. It will allow you to create a form in your forms.py, render that form in your template, and validate it in an orderly fashion.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormView